# pasting correct if statement (indented with '\t') in terminal (bash) gives syntax error

Tags: bash, ubuntu, if-statement, terminal, syntax-error

I get syntax error and a prompt 'Display all 2733 possibilities? (y or n)' when I paste the following in terminal in ubuntu 14.04. The lines are indented with '\t' characters. No errors if I replace '\t' with space characters. Is the terminal treating '\t' specially and showing options, therefore? need help - What is the problem here?

```
    if [ $x -eq 1 ]; then
        cat non-existent-file;
    fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an interactive session <kbd>Tab</kbd> triggers auto-complete. Bash doesn't know that you're pasting text. It sees a copy-and-pasted `\t` the same as if you pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd> on the keyboard.

Normally you type part of a long command name then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to auto-complete the rest of it. If you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> at an empty prompt then auto-complete matches every single program in your `$PATH`, all 2,733 of them.